# Autofilter parts of multiple arguments

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to use the AutoFilter function in VBA.

I have cells in this column filled with values that start with a value that I want to filter on like "pathogenic", "polymorfism", "VUS",... but ends with some more text that I don't want to use in the filter.

e.g.

| variant | class |
| --- | --- |
| V600E | pathogenic variant - BRAF |
| V590A | VUS - D1234567 |
| G12D | pathogenic variant - KRAS |
| G15A | polymorfism |
| A56D | polymorfism - KFP |
| E4654M | presumably pathogenic variant |

In this case I want to filter all rows where the class starts with "pathogenic variant","VUS" and "presumably pathogenic variant", in the example row 1-3 and row 6.

I found a way to use the autofilter for 2 values:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BB$550").AutoFilter _
  Field:=17, _
  Criteria1:=("=patho*"), _
  Operator:=xlOr, _
  Criteria2:=("=VUS*"), _
  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I can't use more then 2 criteria. When I use the following code the filtering doesn't work.

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BB$550").AutoFilter _
  Field:=17, _
  Criteria1:=Array("=patho*", "=VUS*", "=presumably patho*"), _
  Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: You did nothing wrong, you just can't have more than two filter values with wild cards at once. A workaround would be to write the column to an array, loop it and replace each match with a dummy value, write the array back to an extra column, filter the range in the extra column by the dummy value, do what you wanna do (delete or copy) and finally delete the extra column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Filter.

- Columns A and B: Your range
- Column D: Criteria
- Column F and G: Extract

[image]

You you want to **Filter in Place** instead of using **Copy** uncomment the last line.

```
Sub AdvFilter()
    Dim yourRange As Range
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim extractRange As Range
    
    Set yourRange = Range("A1:B25")
    Set criteriaRange = Range("D1:D4")
    Set extractRange = Range("F1:G1")
    
    ' Advanced filter: Copy
    yourRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=criteriaRange, CopyToRange:=extractRange, Unique:=False
    
    ' Advanced filter: Filter in Place
    'yourRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, criteriaRange:=criteriaRange, CopyToRange:=extractRange, Unique:=False
End Sub
```